# Can I invert my ROC curve to plot the true negative against the false negative rate?

Tags: machine-learning, roc

I am trying to understand, if it makes sense to "invert" the ROC curve to display the true negative rate against the false negative rate.

I included a picture for clarification. Is it possible to make that assumption?

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGZ2V.jpg

Comment: Can you clarify in which context you'd like to use it? By the way it won't look like the picture you showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to see in which application it would make sense. And I see several reasons not to do it:

1. The plot shows no extra information than a ROC curve
2. The plot looks like a ROC curve but isn't. People who know what a ROC curve is will think it's a ROC curve. But it isn't.
3. Even you are confused, as exemplified by [your picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGZ2V.jpg) which is actually incorrect.

Here is a quick look at what it would look like:

[image: A ROC curve and a False negative rate vs True negative rate curve]

See how the curve is subtly "reversed", but not as you expected?

I would argue than unless you can bring some very strong reason to do it, you should probably refrain from it and show a standard ROC curve instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I really appreciate it!

So a quick clarification on why I plan to do this: I am currently designing a study, where participants have to make a trade-off decision with an "adjustable algorithm".
As the Information is the same, I think it would be better to understand for non-IT participants(which aren't familiar with ROC curves)to overlay ROC and true negative/false negative rates in one graph with two y-axis. Imagine the context is similar to this article: Link below --> Let more thieves go to prevent false positives. Does that make sense?

Comment: https://gizmodo.com/teen-sues-apple-for-1-billion-claiming-facial-recogni-1834239825

Comment: In this case you might want something more like this: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ROC_curves.svg

Comment: Thats great thanks. I'll try to program this (I'm fairly new to programming in R/Shiny/Javascript), so far the other option seems to be easier to do. I'll do my best in looking for solutions as I think this would be the more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do that.  But to me, it is also representing the same information.

Comment: Thats true, I need this clarification for a project I'm doing. Thanks!